# One Card Poker Expected Value

Tags: descriptive-statistics, game-theory

At my local casino there is a one card poker game with the rules as follows:

The game is essentially WAR you get a card and the dealer gets a card. To beat the dealer you need a higher value card (in this case Ace is higher than King). There is a side bet which I believe gives the player an advantage.

Primary Bet:

**Lose:** -100% bet
**Tie:** -50% Bet
**Win:** +100% Bet

**Tie Side Bet:**
10x side bet

Now I ran a simulation with 5,000,000 hands played and learned this:

Player **WINS: 42.75%**
Player **TIES: 14.50%**
Player **LOSES: 42.75%**

Now for the betting:

PRIMARY BET: \$5
SIDE BET: \$5

If I calculate the expected value this is what I get:

(The win portion is 0 because you double your primary but lose your side bet breaking even)

E[V] = (\$0 * 0.4275)+(\$47.5 * 0.145)+(-\$10 * 0.4275) = $3.0875

Based on the calculation, this is a winning game? Right?

If not what calculations would prove otherwise?

Comment: I don't understand your simulation because the results look wrong.  In a standard deck of 52 cards, with four of each rank, the chance of a tie when dealing two cards from a full randomized deck is only $3/51=5.88\%.$ Have you perhaps not given the full details of the game?

Comment: The chance of a tie is 3/51 without replacement, or 4/52 with replacement. How do you find a roughly 1 in 7 chance of matching the dealer's card when there are 13 different card values?

Comment: My simulation is wrong because I was using blackjack deck values so all the face cards were the same value. Thank you for catching that!

Comment: The 47.5 profit should be a 40 profit.

Comment: Is the deck being reshuffled after a certain moves, or is there some way possible to count the cards? Can the side bet be any value or does it have to match your main bet? Are you allowed to place the side bet without playing the other hands? How many decks are being used?

Comment: I have the 6 deck shoe shuffled after 85% of it has been used and I believe (not 100%) the side bet must be exactly the primary bet and must be played with the primary bet.

Comment: also with all the correct card values in the simulation I'm getting a 7.5% tie rate which still doesn't provide positive EV

Answer (score 2):

To do this without simulations use the following:

Let there be $n$ different types of cards and the number of cards of each type be $k_1, k_2, \dots, k_n$, then the probability that a draw of two cards results in two of the same type is

$$P(draw) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{k_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i} \cdot \frac{k_i-1}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n k_i\right)-1}$$

In the case of 4 two's, 4 three's, 4 fours, 4 fives, 4 sixes, 4 sevens, 4 eights, 4 nines, 4 tens, 4 knaves, 4 queens, 4 kings, 4 aces, you get

$$P(draw) = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{13} 4\cdot 3}{ 52\cdot 51} = \frac{3}{51}$$

In the case of 4 two's, 4 three's, 4 fours, 4 fives, 4 sixes, 4 sevens, 4 eights, 4 nines, 16 tens plus face cards, 4 aces

$$P(draw) = \frac{ 16\cdot 15 + \sum_{i=1}^{9} 4\cdot 3}{ 52 \cdot 51} = \frac{29}{221} \approx 0.1312 $$

And when you play with 6 times as many cards

$$P(draw) = \frac{ 96\cdot 95 + \sum_{i=1}^{9} 24\cdot 23}{ 312 \cdot 311} = \frac{587}{4043} \approx 0.1452 $$

#### Card counting strategy

In the comments you mentioned that the game works with 6 decks that are reshuffled after approximately 5 decks are played. In that case you can beat this game when you are allowed to increase the bet.

But, you have to wait for a long time in order to get a situation where the probability of a draw is above 10%, the level that is neccesary for the game to be in favour for the player, and you would have to wage an incredibly large amount of money beyond practical limits.

Here are the result from 1000 simulated games, in none of the cases did the draw probability go beyond 10%

[image: example of draw probability during 1000 simulated games]

```r
### simulating 6 decks with 13 type of cards each 4 repetitions
### out of these 312 cards 
### we make 130 draws of pairs (= 5 decks) each time computing the probability of a draw
simulate = function() {
   cards = rep(4*6,13) 
   pdraw = rep(NA,130) ### variable to store the evolution of draw probabilities 
   for (i in 1:130) {
      sel = which(cards >0)
      sel2 = which(cards >1)
      pdraw[i] = sum(cards[sel2]*(cards[sel2]-1))/sum(cards)/(sum(cards)-1)
      draw = sample(1:13,1,prob = cards)
      cards[draw] = cards[draw] -1 
      draw = sample(1:13,1,prob = cards)
      cards[draw] = cards[draw] -1 
   }
   return(pdraw)
}

set.seed(1)

plot(simulate(), type = "l", ylim = c(0.055,0.10), 
     xlab = "turn", 
     ylab = "probability for draw", 
     col = rgb(0,0,0,0.1), 
     main = "simulation of evolution of draw probabilities in 1000 games")

for (i in 1:999) {
   lines(1:130,simulate(), col = rgb(0,0,0,0.1))
}

lines(c(-10,150),c(0.1,0.1), lty=2, col = rgb(0,0,0,0.5))
```

Comment: This is correct. I was getting 14.5% because all the face cards were the same value. The game however is played where each consecutive face card is valued higher than the previous, so my simulation was completely wrong. The EV wouldn't be positive and in fact would be about -$1.

Comment: I have heard of a betting strategy that in theory could work, but I'd need to take into account the "Risk of Ruin" or Ruin Theory, since the betting strategy increases every time you tie or lose and in theory could increase until I have no money left. I'm trying to find a way to beat this game, but It may not be possible long term.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the betting value during the game? In that case you can play with pennies and bet a thousand dollars at the moment that the stakes are better. Although you will have to wait for a long time to get the possibility that the advantage is high.

Comment: So the minimum bet is $5 and I've thought about counting the cards, but it's pointless since the dealer has an equal chance of getting the high cards as you do, so there is no statistical advantage to counting the cards and betting higher when the count is high.

Comment: I believe the only strategy is increasing your bets when you lose then reducing it down to the minimum when you win, but the Ruin Theory eventually takes hold and bankrupts you long term. In the short term it's probably a viable strategy.

Comment: What is the maximum bet? If there would be no limit then you can get an advantage by counting cards. There is no advantage in the winning/loosing, but in the draws you can make a difference. You keep betting 5$ untill the stakes for a draw are above 10% and then you bet millions to recover your losses.

Comment: That is a fair point, you could count the cards and wait for a high density of high or low cards, which may give you the side bet advantage. I believe the maximum is $5000.

Comment: That means that you will need to get a sufficiently decent advantage with a large enough probability and high enough rate that a thousand times higher bet can pay back the waiting. This may not be the case.

Comment: Yeah it's really not a winning game even if you card count. The only method to winning is the martingale method which is only viable short term. It's pretty much playing roulette.

Comment: Guess I'll go back to card counting blackjack.

Comment: @altheconda it is not as bad as I thought. Towards the end of the game a lot of cards are out of the game or diminished in number and the draw probability drastically increases. The state of a non homogeneous distribution in the number of cards is advantageous.

Comment: "*The probability of a draw will increase during the game as the game starts to contain less cards.*" — How does that work? Why should the distribution of the last N cards be different from the distribution of the first N cards?

Comment: @RayButterworth after a night sleep I don't see either how that would work, I have deleted the section.

Comment: I mean that could be true. What if there were no 6s drawn in 4 decks out of 6 in the shoe. That means there are 24 6 cards left in only 104 total cards.  So the probability of a tie with 6 would be 23/103 or 22%. So it would be advantageous. The challenging part would be counting exactly which cards haven’t come out in the 4/6 of the shoe that’s been used and the fact that it’s not likely this would happen.

Comment: Shouldn't the denominator be (sum of ks)*(sum of ks - 1), rather than (sum of ks)^2?

Comment: @AccidentalStatistician that's right, probably that's what created my error in simulations of the card counting strategy.

Comment: @altheconda I don't understand what happens in my computations that makes the draw probability increase, but Ray's comment makes sense. When we randomly shuffle the cards, then there is no difference between the positions and the probability of a draw in the beginning or in the end should be the same.

Comment: A priori, the draw probability for later rounds without reshuffling is the same, but the probability conditional on drawn cards can vary. It might increase, but it might also decrease: for example, we could end up with no pairs left in the deck.

Comment: @AccidentalStatistician I tried to compute the variation and probability of an advantage, by using simulations (in one of the previous version of my post) and the weird thing is that every single round there was an increase of the draw probability.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus What an amazing visualization. What'd you use to make it and what language did you use to create the simulation? Edit: Just saw you posted the code! Although are you using seaborn?

Comment: @altheconda The code is written in the language R (see https://www.r-project.org/). You should be able to get the graph is other languages. The trick is the use of transparency when drawing the lines.

Answer (score 2):

To accompany the probabilities described by Sextus, suppose the probability of a tie is $p$. Outside of ties, both players have the same probability $(1-p)/2$ of winning a hand.

For the main bet, winning and losing have equivalent loss/gain amounts and have equal probability, so they cancel out, leaving the expected value as $-p$ times the bet.

For the side bet, we have expected value $10p - (1-p) = 11p - 1$ times the side bet. The expected gain from this side bet alone is positive for $p > 1/11$.

Put together, if our side bet is $s$ times the main bet, we have expected gain $(11s-1)p - s = (11p-1)s - p$. As with the side bet, this can only be positive if $p > \frac{1}{11}$, in which case we require $s > \frac{p}{11p-1} = \frac{1}{11} \frac{p}{p-\frac{1}{11}}$.

In the given game, $p = \frac{3}{51} < \frac{1}{11}$, so making this a winning game is impossible. As expected, taking the side bet would only increase the house edge to be larger than $p$.

It is possible that card-counting could make the expected gain positive for certain rounds: changes in card composition only affect the outcome via the value of $p$, so once card-counting indicated that $p > \frac{1}{11}$, a large enough side bet could make the hand worth playing. If the side bet has to be the same size as the main bet, i.e. $s = 1$, then the expected gain is $10p - 1$, and we'd require $p > \frac{1}{10}$.